# SonarQube - mvn sonar : sonar - NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube

I have a project on SonarQube but when I try to update it with the follow command in the terminal it gets me the this error :

> [ERROR] NoSuchElementException
>   [ERROR]
>   [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
>   [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

I have searched online but apparently nobody knows the answer, so I thought I'd give it a try.

I have the following project structure:

- Project name

  - Dal
  - SharedModel
  - WebsocketClient
  - WebsocketServer

So in total I have 4 modules. My main pom.xml looks like this :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>
  <groupId>myproject.nl</groupId>
  <artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <modules>
    <module>websocketserver</module>
    <module>websocketsclient</module>
    <module>sharedmodel</module>
    <module>Dal</module>
  </modules>
  <name>PartieKo</name>


  <dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
      <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- JUnit 5 -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
      <version>5.5.2</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>11</source>
          <target>11</target>
        </configuration>

      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your command is wrong:

```
mvn sonar : sonar   // WRONG
```

Remove the spacers between sonar and sonar and add the Sonar server address:

```
mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.host.url=https://mysonarserver:9000
```

The sonar server configuration can also be configured in the pom.xml file (add in the properties section)

```
<properties>
    ...
    <sonar.host.url>https://mysonarserver:9000</sonar.host.url>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 0):

Command mvn sonar scanner on windows

```
mvn sonar:sonar `
  "-Dsonar.projectKey=xxxxx" `
  "-Dsonar.host.url=http://local:9000" `
  "-Dsonar.login=xxxxxxxxx"
```

Linux
After adding project on sonar console manualy,sonar will give you the next command.

```
mvn sonar:sonar \
  "-Dsonar.projectKey=xxxxx" \
  "-Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000" \
  "-Dsonar.login=xxxxxxxxx"
```

You can also put url/host/login in pom file or env config.